# Exporting or Copying Visual Studio 6.0 Settings

Tags: visual-studio

I want to copy my visual studio 6.0 (c++) color scheme settings to another computer but I'm having trouble finding where these are stored.  Does anyone know where the file is that stores these settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Format` but I'm not sure if all of it is under Format, you probably want some of the stuff under `Text Editor\Tabs/Language Settings\C/C++` as well.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you.  I exported the settings from both of those registry hive locations and imported them on my other machine and it worked nicely.